# how to solve the problem of getting printed lines with command sudo?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sudo, ros

i was trying to install ROS on ubuntu 18.04
then after a multiple of failure i found that i have done something wrong with the system. that when i open the terminal there is this lines:

```
bash: /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

and when i try to run `sudo -s`
it asks for the password then prints the same lines again.
it seems that i made changes to a file in the system with the cat command.
how can i get rid of this or how to solve the problem if there is one?

Comment: open `~/.bashrc` in an editor, you will find `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` probably at the end of the file (4 of them).

Comment: Thank you. i managed to delete those lines.

Comment: Is there any thing i can do to make sure that i didn't damage any thing else?

Comment: You can see if there are some packages left on the system with `dpkg -l | grep ros-indigo`, remove them with `apt-get remove --purge <package>` last you probably have a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`.

Comment: Think [Melodic](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) are suited for *18.04*. Indigo seems EOL.